# Channel timeout - Reusing and Disposing of a WCF channel within a Proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, service, proxy, channel

In many SOF threads, people are debating how to dispose Channels or ChannelFactories the right way.
I therefore did get a good grasp of what should be done here.
However, my system is a bit unconventional in the sense that the implementation of Proxy Client is not provided to the user.
In other words, if someone wants to create an application that requires to communicate with my service, it has to do it using the provided Proxy dll.

Now, this Proxy dll is the one creating the channel factory and the channels. So far so good. My base class is the one caching the Factory (caching not provided here for simplicity), which is therefore only instantiated once at construction.

The problem I am having is that these proxies expose many methods, each of which needs to use a channel in order to communicate with the service.
I however would prefer for a new channel to be created on each method call, rather than keeping a same channel alive forever (which is what I currently do and is bad!).

So here is what I have so far:

The base class responsible for creating the channel factory:

```
public abstract class MyProxyBase<T> : IMyProxyBase, IDisposable
{
    protected dynamic _channel { get; set; }

    protected DuplexChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory = default;

    protected readonly object _locker = new object();

    public T CreateChannelFactory(string serviceName)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            var ctx = new InstanceContext(DeviceManagerCallbackProxy.Instance);

            string baseAddress = Constants.ServiceBaseAddress;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName))
                serviceName = Constants.DefaultServiceName;
                
            switch (typeof(T).Name)
            {

                case nameof(ISomeService1):
                    baseAddress += "1/";
                    break;

                case nameof(ISomeService2):
                    baseAddress += "2/";
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new SystemException();
            }
                

            var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(); // (serviceName);
            binding.MaxConnections = 10;
            binding.OpenTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            binding.CloseTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            binding.SendTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            _channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<T>(ctx, binding,
                new EndpointAddress(baseAddress + serviceName));

            // Create channel to a specified endpoint
            // !!! I probably should not be creating a channel at this stage - But only when needed instead!
            _channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();

            return _channel;
        }
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_channelFactory != null)
        {
            if (_channelFactory.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Try to close the channel normally
                    _channelFactory.Close();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    // Handle the timeout exception
                    _channelFactory.Abort();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException)
                {
                    // Handle the communication exception
                    _channelFactory.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A given proxy to be compiled and provided to a customer as a dll:

```
public class MyProxyX : MyProxyBase<ISomeService1>, IMyProxyX
{
    // Constructor
    public MyProxyX (string serviceName)
    {
        // Get Channel out of new Channel Factory
        _channel = CreateChannelFactory(serviceName);

    }

    // Some methods using the channel
    public bool DoSomething()
    {

       return _channel?.DoSomething();
    }

    // There are many other methods of the type
    // ....
}
```

So now, considering the only thing the user will see when using this dll are the public methods of the Proxy, I want channels to be properly handled/dispose from within the Proxy class.

Maybe a good way to do that is to always create a new channel each time a Method is called in MyProxyX().
Meaning instead of doing _channel.?DoSomething(), we could do something of the sort (but then how can I make sure the previous channels get properly garbage collected?):

```
// Create a new Channel instead of using _channel
protected SomeService1 MyCurrentChannel 
{
    get { return _channelFactory.CreateChannel(); }
}
```

And finally have DoSomething() implemented this way:

```
public bool DoSomething()
{    
   return MyCurrentChannel?.DoSomething();
}
```

But then I don't want to have to Dispose manually of the channel after each method call. In other words, doing the following thing for each method would be uggly:

```
public bool DoSomething()
{    
   bool pass = MyCurrentChannel?.DoSomething();
   MyCurrentChannel.Dispose();
   return pass;
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        (MyCurrentChannel as ICommunicationObject).Close();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException)
    {
        (MyCurrentChannel as ICommunicationObject).Abort();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        (MyCurrentChannel as ICommunicationObject).Abort();
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}
```

Any help on that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think we need to close the Channel manually. If Channels is not used for a long time, it will be closed automatically.

Comment: @DingPeng, thanks, but I don't think that hoping for it to timeout at some point is the way to do it. What if your max number of channels get reached then? Things will stop working.

Comment: Will wait in line if the maximum number of channels is reached.